# How do I check if two arrays are equal in Zig?

Tags: arrays, zig

If I have two arrays of the same length -- for example, two `[32]u8` --, how can I compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: *just loop through all their values and check if they are equal*.

There is a method that does specifically this in the standard library: [`std.mem.eql`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:mem.eql).

```js
var array1: [32]u8 = undefined;
var array2: [32]u8 = undefined;
if (std.mem.eql(u8, array1, array2)) {
  std.debug.print("they are equal!\n", .{});
}
```

There are also other functions in that same module that may be useful, such as [`std.mem.startsWith`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:mem.startsWith).

Comment: worth pointing out though that looping and checking for equality and using `std.mem.eql` are _not_ equivalent. This works for primitive types, but as soon as you have e.g. structs with padding or anything else which has a notion of equality other than "identical bit patterns" this won't work anymore.